# How to fix thread handle leak caused by connection pooling in application running as service?

Tags: c#, .net, garbage-collection

### Problem

One of our unmanaged Windows services occasionally calls a method in .NET, which opens a database connection. Starting with the first call to that method, the service consumes more and more thread handles over time (hours) until no further applications can be started. The threads created do not continue running, but the corresponding handles are not being released.

This is what the process looks like in ProcExplorer after a few hours (being idle), list of threads doesn't fit the screen anymore:

[image: ProcExplorer view]

#### System info

- Same issue with both .NET 4.0 and 4.6
- OSes tested so far: Win7, Server 2008R2, Server 2003 R2
- Database systems: MS SQL and MS Access

### Analysis

Using .NET Memory Profiler, it became apparent that the process accumulates a lot of .NET `Thread` objects, which do not get finalized. This explains how threads no longer run, but still consume handles.

The next question was where all the threads were coming from, which could also be answered with this tool:

[image: Thread Creation in MemProfiler]

So the execution of some `Timer` creates a new thread using the `CurrentThread` property (unfortunately, the implementation details of this method are not accessible through the .NET reference source). This explains why threads are created continuously (though I wonder why this property would have to create a new thread on every call).

Next question of course is where the timer(s) are coming from. Luckily, there only is a single one, created like this:

[image: Timer creation]

This explains why the first call to a .NET function starts the problem.

### Workaround

Based on this information, we created the following method as workaround which solves the problem and is called one on start of the service:

```
public static void StartGC()
{
    Thread thread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(delegate
    {
        while (true)
        {
            Thread.Sleep(30000);
            GC.Collect();
            GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
            GC.Collect();
        }
    }));

    thread.IsBackground = true;
    thread.Start();
}
```

### Questions

Apparently, the GC is not running soon enough, or at all as it would seem. Why is that? I could imagine that the GC thinks cleaning up the Thread objects (consuming little memory) is not worth it, but at some point it should be cleaning them up anyway.

Also, should `CurrentThread` really create new threads? Is there a way to prevent that from happening? If not, is there a prettier workaround than the one we currently have?

Comment: have you ever found the fix not a workaround? @floele

Comment: @misshomme Nope. Though it may be that .NET 4.7.1 has a fix for it. At least the changelog (see https://github.com/Microsoft/dotnet/blob/master/releases/net471/dotnet471-changes.md, section CLR) has a fix that sounds very much like my problem, but I never verified it.